# extract column names from sql query after where clause

Tags: java, sql, where-clause

I've a requirement where I need to pull out data from database. 
The query is-

```
SELECT e.Data AS EntityBlob, f.Data AS FpmlBlob 
FROM [Trades.InventoryRecord] ir, EntityBlob e, FpmlBlob f 
WHERE %s AND uid = e.uid AND uid = f.uid
```

Here %s is the predicate after where clause which user will input from an html form.

User input will be in this form :
1. TradeDate = '`2013-04-05`' AND IsLatest = 'TRUE'
2. StreamId= '`IA0015`'
3. The query may have IN clause also

Now when this query is rendered I get exception ambigous column streamId or ambigous column IsLatest, as these columns exists in more than one table with same name. So to remove this ambiguity I need to modify the query as - ir.IsLatest or ir.StreamId

To do so by java code, I need to first parse the predicate after where clause, extract  column names and insert table name alias- 'ir' before each column name so that the query becomes -

```
SELECT e.Data AS EntityBlob, f.Data AS FpmlBlob 
FROM [Trades.InventoryRecord] ir, EntityBlob e, FpmlBlob f 
WHERE ir.TradeDate = '2013-04-05' AND ir.IsLatest = 'TRUE' AND uid = e.uid AND uid = f.uid
```

what is the best way to parse this predicate, or if there is any other way I can achieve the same result?

Comment: Does your code allow me to input `1 = 1; DROP TABLE [Trades.InventoryRecord]; --`?

Comment: Drop cant happen as select query is given using a property file in code. only the predicate will come from user. 1=1 is allowed

Comment: Does your code guard against me entering a StreamId of `'; DROP TABLE ..`?

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this question is to not parse the user input - there is **far** too much that can go wrong. It would be a lot better to have a UI with drop downs and buttons for selecting equality, inequality, ranges, in statements, etc. It may seem like more work, but protecting yourself from a SQL injection attack is even more. And even if you are not concerned about malicious SQL injection, then the user still has to get every thing **exactly** right, or the statement fails.

Comment: Yes Jonny you are correct, I had suggested the same, but client wants it in this way only(by taking input in the form of a predicate).

Comment: In that case, I am not sure how much I can help out. As I said earlier - there is a lot that can go wrong.